# Вывести слоты времени с шагом

Tags: php

мне нужно вывести расписание авто моек с возможностью записи,
Каждая авто мойка работает по времени с ... и  до ...
Отсюда логичный вывод что нужно сделать слоты времени начиная там с 10:00 до 20:00 с промежутком (шагом) в 30 минут допустим, как это реализовать?
Именно вывод слотов...

Comment: А у вас какие предложения?

Comment: в том то и дело, что их нету( Есть предложения по записи и сравнение слотов с теми что заняты в бд, а вот сам вывод времени с шагом, пусто*(

Comment: *а вот сам вывод времени с шагом* В чём проблема-то - посчитать эти точки времени (начала тайм-слотов) или вывести их (на экран)?

Comment: Создать цикл слотов с определенным шагом, временем начала и конца

Comment: Смотрите в сторону DateInterval, либо CarbonInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Решение конечно же очень простое...

```
<?php

$slot_start = "09:30";
$slot_end = "19:00";
$slot_step = 30;

for(
    $i = strtotime($slot_start);
    $i <= strtotime($slot_end);
    $i = $i + $slot_step * 60
) {
    $slots[] = date("H:i", $i);
}

print_r($slots);
```

**Результат**:

```
array:20 [▼
  0 => "09:30"
  1 => "10:00"
  2 => "10:30"
  3 => "11:00"
  4 => "11:30"
  5 => "12:00"
  6 => "12:30"
  7 => "13:00"
  8 => "13:30"
  9 => "14:00"
  10 => "14:30"
  11 => "15:00"
  12 => "15:30"
  13 => "16:00"
  14 => "16:30"
  15 => "17:00"
  16 => "17:30"
  17 => "18:00"
  18 => "18:30"
  19 => "19:00"
]
```